# What is the probability space/measure here? In general, what does "almost sure" convergence mean when a probability space is not explicitly specified?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

In a set of lecture notes (on measure theoretic probability) that I'm going through, this is an exercise:

> Suppose $\{\xi_k\}$ are i.i.d. positive integer valued random variables,
> with $P(\xi_1 = i) = p_i > 0$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots$. Let $D_\ell = |\{\xi_1, \dots , \xi_\ell\}|$ denote the number of distinct elements among the first $\ell$ variables.
> Show that $D_n \rightarrow \infty$ almost surely as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm still not quite used to the idea that we could define just a random variable without explicit reference to the probability space it is defined on. I'm having trouble knowing how to frame what this question is asking in a mathematically rigorous way - in my mind, almost sure convergence only makes sense when we have an underlying sample space on which $D_n$ is defined. Do I explicitly construct one (if so, what is the "right" way to do it and is our result independent of the construction we choose?), and then use Kolmgorov's consistency theorem? Or is it simpler than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters in order to establish the almost sure convergence of a sequence $(Y_n)_n$ is the law of the sequence. If you have two probability spaces
$(\Omega_1,\mathcal F_1,\mathbb P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal F_2,\mathbb P_2)$ and sequences of random variables $(Y_{n,i})_{n\geqslant 1}$, $i=1,2$, such that
$\mathbb P_1\left((Y_{n,1})_{n\geqslant 1}\in B\right)=\mathbb P_2\left((Y_{n,2})_{n\geqslant 1}\in B\right)$ for each $B\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, then $Y_{n,1}\to 0$ $\mathbb P_1$-almost surely if and only if $Y_{n,2}\to 0$ $\mathbb P_2$-almost surely.

The information on the law of the sequence is usually sufficient in order to establish/disprove almost sure convergence. For example, $(Y_n)$ is independent,
$\mathbb P(Y_n=1)=1/n$ and $\mathbb P(Y_n=0)=1-1/n$, one can prove that $Y_n\to 0$ in probability but not almost surely.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is true. If, for example, if I define sequences of random variables $Y_n$ and $X_n$ on probability space $[0,1]$ with the borel sigma algebra and Lebesgue measure, and 
$ X_n = 1_{\{[0,\frac{1}{n}]\}}$ and $Y_1 = 1_{\{[0,1]\}}, Y_2 = 1_{\{[0,\frac{1}{2}]\}}, Y_3 = 1_{\{[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}= \frac{5}{6}]\}}, Y_4 = 1_{\{[\frac{5}{6},1] \cup [0, \frac{1}{6}]\}},\dots, Y_n = 1_{\{[\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{k}, \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}]\}}$, where we think of this interval as "wrapped around" $[0,1]$ so that the total length is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Then $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same law, but $X_n \rightarrow 0$ as, but $Y_n$ does not. (for every $\omega \in [0,1]$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $Y_n(\omega) = 1)$

Comment: I agree that in your example, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same law for each fixed $n$. But the sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ do not: for example $P(X_1=X_4=1)=1/4$ but $P(Y_1=Y_4=1)=1/3$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, I'm sorry. Yes, that makes sense. 
$X_n \rightarrow 0$ as iff $\mathbb{P}(\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{|X_n| < \epsilon\}) = 1$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, which just depends on the law of the sequence $X_n$.

Comment: Exactly! No need to be sorry; usually that is the mistakes/misunderstanding that makes one make progress.